# Error While Getting Response from SOAP Webservice

Tags: java, android, web-services, soap, android-ksoap2

For Getting the Response from SOAP Webservice i have do the Following as Needed.

**SOAPUI Request :**

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:test="http://test.login/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <test:Login>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <arg0>best_buyer_editor</arg0>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <arg1>welcome</arg1>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <arg2>Mobile</arg2>
      </test:Login>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

**SOAPUI Response :**

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
      <ns2:LoginResponse xmlns:ns2="http://test.login/">
         <return>{"LoginDetails":{"Result":"Success","UserName":"Best Buyer Editor","token":"M7M5RMQU6","rolelist":["buyer_editor","admin_role"],"parties":[{"partynumber":"BEST","type":"self","sites":[{"companyname":"www.bestmanufacture.com","sitecode":"BESTTXUSA-1","siteaddress":"225 E Industrial Blvd Waco USA"},{"companyname":"www.bestmanufacture.com","sitecode":"BESTNYUSA-5","siteaddress":"20 Milburn St Buffalo USA"},{"companyname":"Best Engineers Manufacturing USA Inc","sitecode":"BESTHQ","siteaddress":"8976, Hope vision Lane Simple City USA"},{"companyname":"www.bestmanufacture.com","sitecode":"BESTNYUSA-6","siteaddress":"Cedar &amp; Ellicott Sts Batavia USA"},{"companyname":"www.bestmanufacture.com","sitecode":"BESTTXUSA-2","siteaddress":"9700 Richmond Ave Ste 201 Houston USA"},{"companyname":"www.bestmanufacture.com","sitecode":"BESTTXUSA-4","siteaddress":"3315 Ashlock Dr Houston USA"},{"companyname":"Best Engineers Manufacturing USA Inc","sitecode":"BESTWH","siteaddress":"1021, Industrial Bolevar San Macros City USA"},{"companyname":"www.bestmanufacture.com","sitecode":"BESTNYMEX-10","siteaddress":"271 Madison Ave Ste 1003 New York USA"},{"companyname":"www.bestmanufacture.com","sitecode":"BESTNYUSA-8","siteaddress":"271 Madison Ave Ste 1003 New York USA"},{"companyname":"Best Engineers Manufacturing Europe Inc","sitecode":"BESTMO","siteaddress":"789,Future Vision Towers London GBR"},{"companyname":"www.bestmanufacture.com","sitecode":"BESTNYUSA-7","siteaddress":"1580 Columbia Tpke Ste 5 Castleton On Hudson USA"},{"companyname":"www.bestmanufacture.com","sitecode":"BESTNYMEX-9","siteaddress":"271 Madison Ave Ste 1003 New York USA"},{"companyname":"www.bestmanufacture.com","sitecode":"BESTTXUSA-3","siteaddress":"2821 Lackland Rd Ste 340 Fort Worth USA"}]},{"partynumber":"DHL","type":"sponsors","sites":[{"companyname":"www.dhl.com","sitecode":"DHLTXUSA-2","siteaddress":"11311 N Central Expy Dallas USA"},{"companyname":"www.dhl.com","sitecode":"DHLNYUSA-7","siteaddress":"150 W 22nd St Fl 5 New York USA"},{"companyname":"www.dhl.com","sitecode":"DHLNYMEX-9","siteaddress":"One Markin Lane Wyoming USA"},{"companyname":"www.dhl.com","sitecode":"DHLNYUSA-6","siteaddress":"12685 State Route 38 Berkshire USA"},{"companyname":"www.dhl.com","sitecode":"DHLTXUSA-4","siteaddress":"2221 Canada Dry St Houston USA"},{"companyname":"www.dhl.com","sitecode":"DHLNYUSA-5","siteaddress":"521 5th Ave Rm 2130 New York USA"},{"companyname":"www.dhl.com","sitecode":"DHLTXUSA-1","siteaddress":"6505 N Houston Rosslyn Rd Houston USA"},{"companyname":"www.dhl.com","sitecode":"DHLTXUSA-3","siteaddress":"9405 N County Road 2000 Lubbock USA"},{"companyname":"www.dhl.com","sitecode":"DHLNYMEX-10","siteaddress":"One Markin Lane Wyoming USA"},{"companyname":"www.dhl.com","sitecode":"DHLNYUSA-8","siteaddress":"One Markin Lane Wyoming USA"}]},{"partynumber":"UPS","type":"sponsors","sites":[{"companyname":"www.ups.com","sitecode":"UPSTXUSA-3","siteaddress":"1455 West Loop S Houston USA"},{"companyname":"www.ups.com","sitecode":"UPSNYUSA-8","siteaddress":"1050 Hook Rd Farmington USA"},{"companyname":"www.ups.com","sitecode":"UPSNYMEX-10","siteaddress":"1050 Hook Rd Farmington USA"},{"companyname":"www.ups.com","sitecode":"UPSNYUSA-7","siteaddress":"1400 Broadway Fl 2 New York USA"},{"companyname":"www.ups.com","sitecode":"UPSTXUSA-4","siteaddress":"14902 Sommermeyer St Ste 100 Houston USA"},{"companyname":"www.ups.com","sitecode":"UPSNYMEX-9","siteaddress":"1050 Hook Rd Farmington USA"},{"companyname":"www.ups.com","sitecode":"UPSNYUSA-6","siteaddress":"101 Cranbrook Ext Tonawanda USA"},{"companyname":"www.ups.com","sitecode":"UPSNYUSA-5","siteaddress":"290 Barrett Hill Rd Mahopac USA"},{"companyname":"www.ups.com","sitecode":"UPSTXUSA-2","siteaddress":"11308 Midmorning Dr Austin USA"},{"companyname":"www.ups.com","sitecode":"UPSTXUSA-1","siteaddress":"3900 Harrisburg Blvd Houston USA"}]},{"partynumber":"HDEPO","type":"sponsors","sites":[{"companyname":"Home Depot USA.","sitecode":"HDEPOWH","siteaddress":"55031 Hdepo WH Road Bossier City USA"},{"companyname":"www.homeDepot.com","sitecode":"HDEPONYUSA-8","siteaddress":"166 Haverford Rd Hicksville USA"},{"companyname":"www.homeDepot.com","sitecode":"HDEPOTXUSA-4","siteaddress":"4901 Blaffer St Houston USA"},{"companyname":"Home Depot USA.","sitecode":"HDEPOHQ","siteaddress":"5031 Hdepo HQ Road Bossier City USA"},{"companyname":"www.homeDepot.com","sitecode":"HDEPONYMEX-9","siteaddress":"166 Haverford Rd Hicksville USA"},{"companyname":"www.homeDepot.com","sitecode":"HDEPONYUSA-6","siteaddress":"1790 Broadway Ste 702 New York USA"},{"companyname":"www.homeDepot.com","sitecode":"HDEPOTXUSA-3","siteaddress":"2203 Timberloch Pl Ste 252 The Woodlands USA"},{"companyname":"www.homeDepot.com","sitecode":"HDEPONYMEX-10","siteaddress":"166 Haverford Rd Hicksville USA"},{"companyname":"www.homeDepot.com","sitecode":"HDEPONYUSA-5","siteaddress":"1040 Avenue Of The Americas New York USA"},{"companyname":"Home Depot USA.","sitecode":"HDEPOMO","siteaddress":"5031 Hdepo MO Road Bossier City USA"},{"companyname":"www.homeDepot.com","sitecode":"HDEPOTXUSA-1","siteaddress":"14603 Chrisman Rd Houston USA"},{"companyname":"www.homeDepot.com","sitecode":"HDEPOTXUSA-2","siteaddress":"16103 University Oak San Antonio USA"},{"companyname":"www.homeDepot.com","sitecode":"HDEPONYUSA-7","siteaddress":"392 Pulteney St Corning USA"}]},{"partynumber":"GWILL","type":"sponsors","sites":[{"companyname":"www.goodwillconstruct.com","sitecode":"GWILLNYMEX-9","siteaddress":"3300 Northern Blvd Fl 2 Long Island City USA"},{"companyname":"GoodWill Supplies and Construction","sitecode":"GWILLHQ","siteaddress":"543, Light Ray Street Wellknown city In"},{"companyname":"www.goodwillconstruct.com","sitecode":"GWILLNYMEX-10","siteaddress":"3300 Northern Blvd Fl 2 Long Island City USA"},{"companyname":"www.goodwillconstruct.com","sitecode":"GWILLNYUSA-7","siteaddress":"1800 New Hwy Farmingdale USA"},{"companyname":"www.goodwillconstruct.com","sitecode":"GWILLNYUSA-8","siteaddress":"3300 Northern Blvd Fl 2 Long Island City USA"},{"companyname":"GoodWill Supplies and Construction","sitecode":"GWILLMO","siteaddress":"6789, Engineering Laner Large city GBR"},{"companyname":"www.goodwillconstruct.com","sitecode":"GWILLTXUSA-2","siteaddress":"945 McKinney St # 237 Houston USA"},{"companyname":"www.goodwillconstruct.com","sitecode":"GWILLNYUSA-6","siteaddress":"580 Broadway Menands USA"},{"companyname":"www.goodwillconstruct.com","sitecode":"GWILLTXUSA-3","siteaddress":"6921 Olson Ln Pasadena USA"},{"companyname":"www.goodwillconstruct.com","sitecode":"GWILLTXUSA-1","siteaddress":"7075 Ranch Road 2338 Georgetown USA"},{"companyname":"www.goodwillconstruct.com","sitecode":"GWILLTXUSA-4","siteaddress":"3839 Dilido Rd Dallas USA"},{"companyname":"www.goodwillconstruct.com","sitecode":"GWILLNYUSA-5","siteaddress":"1 Radisson Plz Ste 803 New Rochelle USA"},{"companyname":"GoodWill Supplies and Construction","sitecode":"GWILLHQ","siteaddress":"543, Light Ray Street Wellknown city USA"},{"companyname":"GoodWill Supplies and Construction","sitecode":"GWILLWH","siteaddress":"2345, Well formed lane Hope in city USA"}]},{"partynumber":"FEDEX","type":"sponsors","sites":[{"companyname":"www.fedex.com","sitecode":"FEDEXTXUSA-2","siteaddress":"400 Langford St Clint USA"},{"companyname":"www.fedex.com","sitecode":"FEDEXNYUSA-8","siteaddress":"3736 Kellogg Rd Cortland USA"},{"companyname":"www.fedex.com","sitecode":"FEDEXTXUSA-4","siteaddress":"5025 East Business 20 Abilene USA"},{"companyname":"www.fedex.com","sitecode":"FEDEXNYUSA-5","siteaddress":"637 New Loudon Rd Ste 2 Latham USA"},{"companyname":"Fedex USA.","sitecode":"FEDEXWH","siteaddress":"6754 Fedex WH  Road Fedex  City USA"},{"companyname":"www.fedex.com","sitecode":"FEDEXTXUSA-1","siteaddress":"4305 N Interstate 35 Denton USA"},{"companyname":"Fedex USA.","sitecode":"FEDEXHQ","siteaddress":"7800 Fedex HQ  Road Bossier City USA"},{"companyname":"www.fedex.com","sitecode":"FEDEXTXUSA-3","siteaddress":"14444 Stuebner Airline Rd Houston USA"},{"companyname":"www.fedex.com","sitecode":"FEDEXNYMEX-10","siteaddress":"3736 Kellogg Rd Cortland USA"},{"companyname":"www.fedex.com","sitecode":"FEDEXNYUSA-7","siteaddress":"65 Old Indian Rd Milton USA"},{"companyname":"www.fedex.com","sitecode":"FEDEXNYMEX-9","siteaddress":"3736 Kellogg Rd Cortland USA"},{"companyname":"Fedex USA.","sitecode":"FEDEXMO","siteaddress":"9600 Fedex MO Road Bossier City USA"},{"companyname":"www.fedex.com","sitecode":"FEDEXNYUSA-6","siteaddress":"1254 Erie Ave North Tonawanda USA"}]}]}}</return>
      </ns2:LoginResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

**MY Code :**

```
URL = "http://test.tpsynergy.com:8080/tpsynergy/services/login";
SOAP_ACTION = "http://test.tpsynergy.com:8080/tpsynergy/services/login";
METHOD = "Login";
NAMESPACE = "http://test.login/";
SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, "Login");
request.addProperty("arg0", "best_buyer_editor");
request.addProperty("arg1", "welcome");
request.addProperty("arg2", "Mobile");

Log.i(TAG, "Request for getting airport list" + request.toString());

SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
envelope.dotNet = true;
HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
try {
    androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

    if (envelope.bodyIn instanceof SoapFault) {
                String str= ((SoapFault) envelope.bodyIn).faultstring;
                Log.i("", str);


     } else {
                SoapObject resultsRequestSOAP = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
                response = resultsRequestSOAP.getProperty(0).toString();

                 Log.i(" Login Webservice Response", "Responce ---->"
                         + (resultsRequestSOAP.getProperty(0).toString()));
            }

    } catch (Exception e) {

            Log.i(TAG, "Exception e" + e.toString());
        }
```

After Executing the above code i am getting Following Error:

```
Unmarshalling Error: unexpected element (uri:"http://test.login/", local:"arg0"). Expected elements are <{}arg2>,<{}arg1>,<{}arg0>
```

Can Anyone Tell me why i am getting Success in SOAPUI bt not through my code.

I have referred many SO link but not able to solve my Problem.

**What My Question :** I really Do not understand Know what the Error is Trying to say by `Expected elements are <{}arg2>,<{}arg1>,<{}arg0>.`  What is the Solution to Get out of this Problem?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use TCP monitor to check what is the SOAP request that is sent. I suspect based on error message, the elements arg* are qualified with the namespace where as the webservice does not expect them that way.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:test="http://test.login/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <test:Login>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <test:arg0>best_buyer_editor</test:arg0>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <test:arg1>welcome</test:arg1>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <test:arg2>Mobile</test:arg2>
      </test:Login>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```